# How to show selected values sent from Controller as List of Objects?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, arraylist

**AddTruck.jsp** Page form below:

```
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="truckDto" action="myController">

       <form:checkbox path="operatingDays[0].weekDays" 
value="MONDAY" class="weekday" id="weekday-mon"/>

       <form:checkbox path="operatingDays[1].weekDays" 
value="TUESDAY" class="weekday" id="weekday-tue"/>
```

// likewise its for all days of week till sunday and the index of `operatingDays` keeps incrementing till end of week.

**TruckDto** has following property of `ArrayList` of Objects:

```
private List<TruckOperatingDays> operatingDays = new ArrayList<TruckOperatingDays>();
//getter setter below
```

**TruckOperatingDays** POJO has following properties with their getter-setter methods:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "week_days")
    private WeekDaysEnum weekDays;

    @Column(name = "opening_hours")
    private String openingHours;

    @Column(name = "closing_hours")
    private String closingHours;
```

When I submit the form, I get values in my controller as needed and I can save the values to my database with no issues. The problem is at the "Edit" time.
When I open this page to edit the values that has been saved previously in database, I fail to get the checkboxes already selected because of the index positions of `operatingDays` are static in the form and the `ArrayList` passed from controller doesn't set values to my input fields/checkboxes in the form.

**Please note that I cannot use JSTL `foreach` loop to generate the form fields from the `ArrayList` because I need to show labels too as Monday, Tuesday etc.**

**Is there any way through which my form fields can automatically bind through my DTO proeprties just like we can bind simple input fields with no issues?**

Answer (score 0):

You can still use JSTL , just add an additional list to store the week days into (NOTE: this example assumes that your ArrayList returns all 7 days but some days may be null( not selected)).

```
<%
    String[] days = new String[]{ "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY" };
pageContext.setAttribute("wDays", days);
    %>
//and then use JSTL
<c:forEach items=${operatingDays} var="day", varStatus="counter">
   <form:checkbox path=${day.weekDays}
   value=${wDays[counter]} class="weekday" id="weekday-mon"/>
</c:forEach>
```

If you would like to avoid scriptlets, you can use <c:set> in your JSP page to populate the week days list or just populate the days list in your Java code (not in JSP)